# Customize configuration in spring boot java using open telemetry automatic instrumentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

I am trying to customize otel configuration pragmatically and used the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class OtelConfig implements AutoConfigurationCustomizerProvider {

        @Override
        public void customize(AutoConfigurationCustomizer provider) {
            System.out.println("Setting OtelConfig");
            provider.addPropertiesSupplier(new Supplier<Map<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> get() {
                    System.out.println("Setting OtelConfig");
                    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
                   // properties.put("otel.trace.sampler", "always");
                    properties.put("otel.exporter.jaeger.endpoint", "http://localhost:14250");
                    return properties;
                }
            });
        }

}
```

But spring is not calling this method. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: are you using opentelemetry-javaagent? or opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter?

Comment: I am able to use this using java agent extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use this using Java agent extensions. Please refer [this](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/examples/extension) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

From code, I think you are trying to test if the configuration successful.

If you **just** write the code you showed, you

1. **register** the *OtelConfig* in Spring.
2. If you want Spring call the method you wrote, you should in somewhere **inject** the bean and call the method.

A bean will **NOT** automaticlly called/used by Spring.

You can

1. In your application configuration, use ApplicationContext and getBean().
2. You should use @Autowired to inject the OtelConfig class which implements Provider interface, and then call the method through a Manager class.
   Just like this [Spring Security Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider).
   This may contain in the tutorial of Otel, I quickly glance it, and not find the similar content.
3. You can write a unit test for the class, but I think the step will like what mentioned in 2.